# ANDROID: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest

Cuando intento compilar mi Android App en Flutter aparece el siguiente error y no tengo la menor idea de cómo leerlo, qué puede ser?

```
E/AndroidRuntime(18988): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(18988): Process: com.aplians.aplians_fish, PID: 18988
E/AndroidRuntime(18988): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.aplians.aplians_fish/com.aplians.aplians_fish.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.aplians.aplians_fish.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.aplians.aplians_fish-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.aplians.aplians_fish-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2313)
E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2466)
E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:152)
E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1341)
E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5538)
E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:958)
E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:753)
E/AndroidRuntime(18988): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.aplians.aplians_fish.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.aplians.aplians_fish-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.aplians.aplians_fish-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2303)
E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    ... 10 more
E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.aplians.aplians_fish.MainActivity
E/AndroidRuntime(18988):        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(18988):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
E/AndroidRuntime(18988):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
E/AndroidRuntime(18988):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
E/AndroidRuntime(18988):        ... 13 more
E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Ayer compiló correctamente e incluso pude obtener el archivo APK previo a la publicación en el PlayStore, sin embargo hoy cuando intento hacer debug desde VS Code me aparece este error en consola y el App se instala en el equipo, pero no es capaz de iniciar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que revisar lo siguiente :

**La estructura de directorios dentro de android**

```
//Si usas java
android/src/main/java/com/aplians/aplians_fish/MainActivity.java

//Si usas kotlin
android/src/main/kotlin/com/aplians/aplians_fish/MainActivity.kt
```

**El nombre del package en la primera linea de la clase MainActivity**

```
package com.aplians.aplians_fish
```

**El `AndroidManifest.xml` de la carpeta main debe apuntar al package correcto**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.aplians.aplians_fish">
```

**El `app\build.gradle` debe contener el applicationId correcto**

```dart
   applicationId "com.aplians.aplians_fish"
```

Comment: gracias. El AndroidManifest y el build.gradle está como tu indicas. En Kotlin encontré el archivo MainActivity.kt y tenía el nombre incorrecto de package (com.example.aplians...). Lo cambié y ya deja instalar el App. Me sigue apareciendo un error del tipo E/FirebaseInstanceId(24216): Failed to resolve target intent service, skipping classname enforcement
E/FirebaseInstanceId(24216): Error while delivering the message: ServiceIntent not found. Es diferente?

Comment: sí, ese es otro error, podrías abrir otro issue acerca de eso con más detalle, si te sirvió mi respuesta puedes marcarla como resuelta